# Rails Edit-Form with all available options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have an object like `@cart` which have a `has_many`relation to `@product`.

Now in my Edit-Form of `@cart` I have the related items of `@product`:

**Cart ID#1234:**

- product#1: amount: 5
- product#6: amount: 10

what I need is that all possible `@products` in the DB will shown with an amount of `0` like this:

**Cart ID#1234:**

- product#1: amount: 5
- product#2: amount: 0
- product#3: amount: 0
- product#4: amount: 0
- product#5: amount: 0
- product#6: amount: 10

and if the user change the amount of one `product` I can save this new amount (respectively relation)

Answer (score 0):

In your `edit` action you can do

```
ProductType.each do |product_type|
  next if @cart.products.where(product_type: product_type.id).empty?
  @cart.build_products(product_type: product_type)
end
```

This will create ALL product types.

Then in your `update` action you can do

```
  if @cart.update_attributes(cart_params)
    @cart.products.each do |product|
      product.destroy if product.amount == 0
    end
...
```

...this to remove the unused products.